# Does stdio always set errno?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, stdio, errno

When a `stdio` stream encounters an error (but not EOF), the stream's error indicator will be set so that `ferror()` will return nonzero.  I have always assumed that more information is available in `errno`.  But how do I know this?

Documentation for some functions [e.g. `man fopen` under Linux] says that `errno` will also be set.  However `man fgets` doesn't mention `errno` at all.   The glibc info pages are reassuring:

> In addition to setting the error indicator associated with the
>   stream, the functions that operate on streams also set `errno' in the
>   same way as the corresponding low-level functions that operate on file
>   descriptors.

But I have no idea how strong this guarantee is.  Is it required by the C standard?  What happens in Visual C/C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C Standard itself does not require much use of errno WRT to `stdio` functions; it specifies `ferror()` but says of it only that

> **7.13.10.3 The ferror function** The ferror function tests the error indicator  for  the stream pointed to by stream. The ferror function returns nonzero if and only if  the error indicator is set for stream.

from the C99 Draft: http://www.vmunix.com/~gabor/c/draft.html.  Any actual error codes used are, for the most part, implementation defined.

However, the GNU C library on linux also conforms to POSIX specifications:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm

Which are much more well defined in this context.  For example, if you look at the page for `fopen`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html

You'll see a lot of detailed information, including specific errno codes, under *Errors*.

Again, the GNU C library used on virtually all normal linux systems is POSIX compliant, so you can count on that information ;).  Those (online) POSIX man pages are also generally more detailed than the standard linux system man pages (read both).

WRT to file operations on other (non-POSIX) platforms, they will have their own implementations.  Unfortunately, stuff like that is not transparently portable in standard C.  C++ streams do have more standardized error handling, though.

Comment: Thanks.  The POSIX definitions are very helpful.  For example, accordng to them, "fgets" does indeed set errno.  I think the best strategy for my particular case is to just write for POSIX and then fix Windows problems as they come up.

Comment: Although GNU's `fopen()` sets `errno`, **`fread()` doesn't**, even if POSIX specifies so (with a _"CX"_ tag). Any ideas why?

Comment: The [POSIX man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html), at least, does not mention this.   I notice the linux man page, though, doesn't mention errno at all.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C11 standard, chapter 7.21 ("stdio.h"), only `fgetpos`, `fsetpos` and `ftell` write to `errno` in the event of an error.