# fread and ferror don't set errno

Tags: c, fread, errno, ferror

I'm trying to check when `fread()` raises an error, so I use `ferror()`.

```
chunk = fread(buf, 1, 100, file);
if (ferror(file))
  {
    return errno;
  }
```

But, `ferror()` man page (`man 3 ferror`, or just `man ferror`) says:

> **ERRORS**
> These functions should not fail and do not set the external variable `errno`.

So, how can I know the error type occurred when file has been read, although `fread()` and `ferror()` didn't set `errno`?

Comment: Did you read [fread(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) ? It has a documented behavior on error !

Comment: yes, it doesn't mention anything about setting errno.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think his point was exactly that. Sure `ferror` can tell you an error happened, but since `fread` is *not* documented to set `errno`, how can he tell *what the actual error was*, if he can at all, since `errno` won't reflect the specific error condition that lit up the stream error state?

Comment: Related: [Does stdio always set errno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672095/does-stdio-always-set-errno).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get there from here.

`fread` does not set `errno` (as you have discovered), and as such you cannot really determine much about a *specific* error state; only that there *is* one. The exact nature of the error is generally implementation-dependent. There is no C standard-library-based portable way to gather it .

For specific system-level errors, you can slum it to system-calls, possibly suffering with the pitfalls like poor/nonexistent IO buffering along the way. There POSIX can somewhat come to your rescue. Calls like [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), *do* set `errno` and have a fairly detailed set of possible outcomes. That may be an option for you if the platform you're working with is POSIX compliant and the code is really so critical to be in-the-know.

But from the C standard library, you're not going to find much beyond being told an error has happened. Generally you'll find you don't need more than that anyway.

Comment: POSIX requires `fread` to set `errno` on an error. From the POSIX documentation on `fread`, "Otherwise, if a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, and `errno` shall be set to indicate the error. "

Comment: @DavidHammen: that snippet is marked as a POSIX _extension_ [CX]. Still, I wonder why GNU does not follow this extension. Isn't it supposed to when `_XOPEN_SOURCE` / `_POSIX_SOURCE` are defined with appropriate values?

Answer (score 4):

Those functions don't use `errno`, so you shouldn't either.

It is worth noting that you can tell if everything went smoothly from the return value of `fread()`. If the return value of `fread()` differs from the passed `nmemb` parameter (100 in your case), then you either reached the end of your file or an error occured reading it ([source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)). So test only in that case:

Just drop the use of errno alltogether:

```
chunk = fread(buf, 1, 100, file);
if (chunk != 100) { // If fread() returns a number different to the nmemb parameter, either error or EOF occured
    if (ferror(file))
      {
        printf("Error occured while reading file.");
        return -1; // Or what ever return value you use to indicate an error
      }
}
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `fread` has documented behavior on error or end of file. You need to use `ferror()` to check if it was an error or `feof()` for end-of-file.